# Programmatically connecting to TFS getting "TF30063: You are not authorized" error

Tags: api, service, tfs, credentials, networkcredentials

I am trying to create a program in c# that allows me to connect to my TFS in order to create new work items.

```
NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(
"username",
"password");
BasicAuthCredential basicCred = new BasicAuthCredential(netCred);
TfsClientCredentials tfsCred = new TfsClientCredentials(basicCred);
tfsCred.AllowInteractive = false;

TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
new Uri("https://example.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection"),tfsCred);

tpc.Authenticate();
```

At the moment when I am trying to make a connection to TFS I am using my own Live username and password which is giving me the error message "TF30063: You are not authorized".  I'm not sure on the different ways to make a connection to TFS.

I believe the correct way is using the service credentials, but at the moment I can't workout how to find out the service credentials only I am not sure how to find out my service credentials within TFS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [enable alternate credentials](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2013/01/07/how-to-connect-to-tf-service-without-a-prompt-for-liveid-credentials.aspx) when connecting to Visual Studio Online with the TFS API.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed.  I wasn't sure where to find the alternate credentials.  Thanks!